# Displaying tables in FormPage & width control

Tags: cloud-deploy, form-building

I've been struggling to make a cloud deployed form whose output is a table of data.
Here is a toy example:

```
CloudDeploy[FormPage["x" -> "Number", TableForm[N[RandomInteger[{1, #x}, {50, 10}], 30]] &], 
  CloudObject["questions/formwidth"], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

This uses TableForm to display the table in a crude way. But I don't know how to format the output table and it looks very bad.

My dream would be to have the output be displayed as a Dataset object.
This can be done, but only if the output is displayed in another window:

```
CloudDeploy[FormFunction["x" -> "Number", ExportForm[TableForm[N[RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {50, 10}], 30]], 
    "CloudCDF"] &], CloudObject["questions/formwidth"], 
     Permissions -> "Public"]
```

I would really appreciate any ideas.
Thanks in advance.